# using _.omit on mongoose User in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, underscore.js

I have a mongoose User schema built like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    salt: { type: String, required: true}
});
```

I want to be able to send this user object to the client side of my application but I don't want to sned the password or salt fields.

So I added he following code to my user model module

U

```
serSchema.methods.forClientSide = function() {
    console.log('in UserSchema.methods.forClientSide');
    console.log(this);
    //var userForClientSide=_.omit(this,'passsword','salt');
    var userForClientSide={_id:this._id, username:this.username };
    console.log(userForClientSide);

    return userForClientSide;
}
```

I have `required` the underscore module (its installed locally via a dependency in my package.js).

not the commented out line - I was expecting it to omit the password and salt fields of the user object but it did not do anything :( the logged object had the full set of properties.

when replaced with the currently used like `var userForClientSide={_id:this._id, username:this.username };` it gets the results I want but:

1) I want to know why does the `_.omit` not work.
2) I don't like my current workaround very much because it actually selects some properties instead of omitting the ones I don't like so if I will add any new propertes to the scema I will have to add them here as well.

This is my first attempt at writing something using node.js/express/mongodb/mongoose etc. so It is very possible hat I am missing some other better solution to this issue (possibly some feature of mongoose )  feel free to educate me of the right way to do things like this.

so basically I want to know both what is the right way to do this and why did my way not work.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1) I want to know why does the _.omit not work.

Mongoose uses `defineProperty` and some heavy metaprogramming. If you want to use underscore, first call `user.toJSON()` to get a plain old javascript object that will work better with underscore without all the metaprogramming fanciness, functions, etc.

A better solution is to use mongo/mongoose's `fields` object and pass the string `"-password -salt"` and therefore just omit getting these back from mongo at all.

Another approach is to use the mongoose [Transform](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) (search for "tranform" on that page). Your use case is the EXACT use case the documentation uses as an example.

You can also make your mongoose queries "lean" by calling `.lean()` on your query, in which case you will get back plain javascript objects instead of mongoose model instances.

However, after trying each of these things, I'm personally coming to the opinion that there should be a separate collection for `Account` that has the login details and a `User` collection, which will make leaking the hashes extremely unlikely even by accident, but any of the above will work.

Comment: thanks, I had a feeling it was not "plain" javascript... as for your suggestion to use `user.toJSON()` looking at the documentation I am a bit confused. I would expect toJSON to return JSON (i.e. a string) and the documentation also says `The return value of this method is used in calls to JSON.stringify(doc)` so I agian, I would expect a String but it says the type returned is an Object. I know javascript strings ARE objects but still - I would not document a method that returns a string as one that returns an object. so I think I might have to use toObject() not toJSON().

Comment: I will also consider the separation of `User` and `Account` as well.

Comment: The names `toJSON` and `stringify` are confusing for everyone - they are just bad names - plain and simple. In mongoose, `toJSON` means something like "to plain data-only javascript object", which you can then pass to `JSON.stringify` to get your actual JSON string.

Comment: So what is the difference betwen toJSON and toObject?

Comment: That is a bit more subtle. toJSON is more generically used across many javascript projects, whereas toObject is a more mongoose-specific, but mongoose let's you customize the behavior via the transform options. I use toObject to get a canonical object on the server side and toJSON as my "wire format" for sending to the browser, but that's just my own convention.