# How to properly drop a Mongoose model field from logging methods?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Working schemas and models using Mongoose I got a `password` field which I have to drop when offering a user to an API.

I need to do something like:

```
var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mongooseUserModel));
delete user.password;
// return ....
```

So for any function in the fashion of `console.log`, `JSON.stringify`, etc I need to make that process implicit.

I'm not trying to exclude password field from queries, it's just I don't want it to be logged.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980461/using-omit-on-mongoose-user-in-node-js

Comment: If you're not doing cleartext passwords, why do you care if they get logged?

Answer (score 0):

The feature [transform](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) should be exactly what you want.

Here is a example for your need:

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
    delete ret.password;  // just delete password field when toJSON
  }
});
```